# Creating an associative array in Rust

Tags: rust, associative-array

I was looking for the way to create an associative array in the documentation but didn't find anything. So how do I create an associative array in Rust?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you know as an associative array is also known by some other names, such as a *dictionary* or a *map*.

In Rust, it’s called a map, and is epitomised in the [`HashMap`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) type.

Comment: When you want ordered associative array, there is also [`BTreeMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html).